# Swift3 - How can I find all keys in Foundation.UserDefaults so I can delete all of my data

Tags: swift3

I have dynamic key generation to build my database so I need to be able to find all the keys the user produced if I wanted to do a full delete.

```
func deleteAllData(){
    let userDefaults = Foundation.UserDefaults.standard
    let keys = userDefaults.dictionaryRepresentation()
    for key in keys {
        print(key)
        userDefaults.removeObject(forKey: String(describing: key))
    }
}
```

So I'm not in the right dictionary because the keys I'm grabbing here contain system info such as AppleLocale, PKKeychainVersionKey, and AppleKeyboards.

I've noticed some functions in UserDefaults such as removeSuite, removeVolatileDomain, and removePersistentDomain. Is there a better way I should be structuring my data so I can use these methods, or can I already use them if I knew what to pass as an argument.

```
// How I've been setting my data
userDefaults.set(taskTime, forKey: "\(taskName)_taskTime")
userDefaults.set(lastRefresh, forKey: "\(taskName)_lastRefresh")


//Swift2.x delete-all method
for key in Array(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryRepresentation().keys) {
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removeObjectForKey(key)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By no means is this the prettiest solution but it should get the job done. I can confirm that `dictionaryRepresentation()` is the closest you're going to get. It does contain all of your keys, unfortunately it contains all of that other stuff as well.

If you named all of your keys how you did in the example you could do something like this since they would all contain an underscore.

```
for key in Array(UserDefaults.standard.dictionaryRepresentation().keys) {

    if key.element.contains("_") {
        UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: key.element)
    }

}
```

Or if an `_` won't work I guess you could check if the key contained `taskTime` or `lastRefresh`.

Comment: Thanks mate, I found a similar solution. Still unhappy that there is some 'floating' data saved to the phone that was creating during development. Wish there was a delete all method